# Pythonic way to use a list as an index (without numpy)

Tags: python, arrays

What is a Pythonic way to use a list as an index in Python?
With numpy you can do the following:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.zeros(10)
indices = [1,3,6]
a[indices] = 1
# This gives [0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0]
```

What is the simplest way to replicate this without using numpy?

Comment: Someone is spamming answers with downvotes - upvote the answers you like and their influence will be insignificant.

Comment: I thought so too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through the indices and update the list manually:

```
a = [0] * 10
for index in indices:
  a[index] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of zeros on your own:

```
a=[0] * 10
>>> a
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

indices = [1,3,6]
for index in indices:
    a[index]=1

>>> a
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe just use a loop and conditionally append to a list

```
a = []
indices = [1,3,6]
for i in range(10):
    if i in indices:
        a.append(1)
    else:
        a.append(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with list comprehension

```
indices = [1,3,6]
a = [1 if i in indices else 0 for i in range(10) ]
# [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: This is what I as going to suggest - a nice clean one-liner.